# Can we call the button using select(A single selection widget) in bokeh?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, bokeh

https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/widgets.html (You can see select)

I want to call a button, text input and slider in using select.

```
plot_button = Button(label="plot") 
color_button = Button(label="Color", disabled=True)
axis_start_value_text = TextInput(title=" Start value=", value="270")
axis_slider = Slider(value=0, start=0, end=100, step=1, title="Title")

button_map = {
    "plot": plot_button,
    "Color": color_button, 
    "Start value": axis_start_value_text,
    "Slider": axis_slider
}
button_call = Select(title="Button call", options=sorted(button_map.keys()), 
value="plot")
```

In the Select button, when I click on a button, text_input and slider the button appears on the screen that I clicked. İs it possible?

Comment: Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: What do you mean by "call a button" ? You want to use the Select widget to show/hide the other widgets based on the selection?

Comment: @Seb Exactly yes

Comment: Please check the edit to my answer, there was a less hacky solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put up an [example app](https://bitbucket.org/rocheseb/bokeh/src/86bc5fa794e3a240228465c8f10256c9d401b7a9/applications/show_hide_widgets/) on bitbucket.

You can give css_classes to your widgets, or widgetbox, and then access the div elements contaning the widgets in a CustomJS callback.

I have not found a way to set the display to None from the start, couldn't do it with customm css. So I use a timeout function, you'd need to tweak the timing of the timeout function if you don't want the widgets to appear before they are made invisible.

**EDIT:** 
I updated the code, in fact there is a clean way to hide the widgets initially without using a timeout callback. I use a custom css for that with `display:none` for all objects with class "hidden". Then in the CustomJS you just need to add or remove the "hidden" to the class name of the widgetboxes.